# starting get_link_state topic?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-electric, rostopic, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Electric and assuming you can only subscribe to a topic or use it as a serviceClient if it is visible using "rostopic echo", which launcher should I use to see /gazebo/get_link_state? As links I now have /gazebo/link_states, ~model_states, ~set_link_state and ~set_model_state/. The ~get_link_state topic is not shown.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60197/starting-get_link_state-topic-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/gazebo/get_link_state` is not a topic but a service. You can use it like this: `rosservice call gazebo/get_link_state '{link_name: cup, reference_frame: world}'` See [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) for more info.

**Update:**

@hvn You have errors in your code: Try this code, it works. I got the output "`link state exists`"

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/GetLinkState.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "forum");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::service::waitForService("gazebo/get_link_state");
ros::ServiceClient gls_client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::GetLinkState>("gazebo/get_link_state");
gazebo_msgs::GetLinkState gls_request;
if (gls_client.exists()) 
{ ROS_INFO("link state exists"); gls_request.request.link_name = string("right_hand"); gls_request.request.reference_frame=string("world"); gls_client.call(gls_request); } 
else 
{ ROS_INFO("Something went wrong"); }
return 0;
}
```

There is a service named /gazebo/get_link_state but no service name get_link_state/pose and the client call you are making is wrong.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1